# Dspace communities name translation

Tags: dspace

I have installed Dspace v4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 and after some research and struggle I've managed to add another language which is not officially supported(Romanian).
Now, I'm aware that some files need manual editing and translation to work with that language(eg. newstop.jsp --> newstop_ro.jsp) but I was wondering if it's possible when you change the language to another one the names for the communities also to change. If so, what should be modified ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add a language specific name to a community in DSpace. This would require changes in the DSpace source code.

Comment: Are developers considering implementing this in future releases?